# <a> </a> in blue print

Tags: css, blueprint-css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperlinks showing URL with Blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258417/hyperlinks-showing-url-with-blueprint)

If i include blueprint all my link in page looks like (if it was link on google.com)
google(http://google.com)+ all unerline but but if i remove blue print links looks fine without brackets ?

what it can be ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean blueprint css? That's because of the following lines in print.css :

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

It's the content:-line that's "bugging" you. Are you including print.css for screen-media too? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: When i look tutorial i understood need include in any page 3 lines
1st if ie and include ie.css
2nd print.css
3dr screen.css 

You mean that ?i think do something wrong in fundamentally?

Comment: You should specify the media-type, like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />

Comment: thank you all work !Recomend great book or resource and toolkit for fast creating (html css side) web page?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the media attribute of your link item is set to "print"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="App_Themes/Default/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

The CSS that is responsible for this looks something like:

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}
```