# Hyperlinks showing URL with Blueprint

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I just converted a site to Blueprint CSS today, and suddenly all my hyperlinks are showing their URL's in brackets, e.g.

This hyperlink

```
<a href="Products/List.aspx">Read more</a>
```

Renders like this

```
Read More (Products/List.aspx)
```

I wonder if this might be related to one of the bundled plug-ins in Blueprint?

**ADDED:** The link renders normally, i.e. the unwanted url part is being generated client-side.  Folks have asked for source code, so here it is (irrelevant text removed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/Blueprint/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/Blueprint/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <a href="Products/List.aspx">Read more</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**SOLVED:**  By removing the 'print.css' sheet that all tutorials suggest including, I was able to solve the problem in this example and my whole site.  I'm still very curious as to why the venerable 'print.css' is acting up like this.

Comment: highly unlikely that this is related to blueprint, namely as css can't add characters in that manner.

Comment: FYI: You can save us a lot of time by just providing the source code.

Comment: @meder, no source code I can provide has anything to do with this.  Although my previous example was data based, it's the same with hard coded <a> tags, as reflected in my new example.

Comment: Please show the generated source code in the browser. Also, does blueprint bring any Javascript modules? This could be a Javascript based extension adding the href to the visible text

Comment: @ProfK - showing us a hyperlink is pretty much useless without showing us the code to the page. That is, unless Ms Cleo is on Stackoverflow.

Comment: OK, @meder, this is 'textbook' source code, i.e. all the tutorials show this, and it still exhibits the problem.  I found what is wrong, but by finding a ruby question on some site unrelated to Blueprint.  I'll post the solution in a minute, I just want to see how relevant the source code is. :-)

Comment: You have yet to show us what the unwanted part is. We basically have no context of the problem, and you want us to solve it. I suggest in the future you provide screenshots and absolute links to working demos of the issue to save everyone time.

Comment: The above code exhibits the problem.  That is what makes the unwanted part 'unwanted'.  See my solution above.

Comment: Was the issue just blueprint generating `:after { content:"("`, etc? That's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: @Ross, that's not correct. See Larsenal's answer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's likely you have something like this in your CSS:

```
a:link:after { content:" (" attr(href) ") "; }
```

That will produce the behavior you describe.

Typically, you would only use this kind of style for the print version of your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks.  That might be what was in the print.css sheet; when I took it out the problem cleared up.

Comment: The `<link>` for your `print.css` should be set to `media="print"` .. The HTML you posted shows that it was defaulting to `media="screen"`, which would make all of those "for printing only" styles to apply to your browser display.

Comment: Thank you @jnpcl.  I've never even looked at the media attribute because I've always always coded purely for screen, i.e. intranet LOB apps.

Comment: @ProfK: If you ever have a page that you expect users to print, it's good to provide a `print.css` to remove unnecessary colors/backgrounds/etc.

Comment: @jnpcl, why not post your answer as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @ProfK: Because the answer that my comment was placed under is the answer you should accept. :)