# Why the href attributes of a tags are printed to screen?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperlinks showing URL with Blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258417/hyperlinks-showing-url-with-blueprint)

DOM:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="/contacts">Contact List</a>
        <a href="/album">Event Album</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Looks weird, why the href are printed?

```
    /* Menu */
#menu{
 width:400px;
 height:50px;
 margin:10px auto;
 border:solid 1px #313131;
 background:#ffffff;
 overflow:hidden;
}
/*------ MENU ------*/

    #menu ul{
     list-style:none;
    }

    #menu ul a{
     text-decoration:none;

    }

    #menu ul a:hover{
     color:#7878ff;

    }
```

Comment: This is something blueprint specific, I remember seeing this in some other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may be grabbing the print.css for the screen.  Make sure you have your media types set properly.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the media attribute of your link item is set to "print"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="App_Themes/Default/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

The CSS that is responsible for this looks something like:

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}
```